# How do I stop IntelliJ IDEA automatically changing FONT_SCALE?

Tags: intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA community (currently 2017.2) from both Windows and Linux with settings shared between the two via the settings repository.  In the main this works well but sometimes I will open IntelliJ from either OS and find the font sizes for the editor, console and UI have increased from 14 to 17.

I notice that when this happens it's because `FONT_SCALE` in `~/.IdeaIC2017.2/config/settingsRepository/repository/ui.lnf.xml` has been changed from 1.0 to 1.25 by the commit made when I previously closed IntelliJ on the other OS.  This seems to happen occasionally in both directions.  I'm not changing anything myself that should affect this.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? The reported bug has not been updated...

Comment: Afraid not.  There was no change in 2017.2 and I still get the same behaviour.  One idea might be to branch and merge manually but I've not tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reported a bug, please follow for updates:

- [IDEA-172611](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172611) Don't share FONT_SCALE setting between different operating systems

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was some sort of auto scale setting governing this but couldn't find any - Thank you!